# Django Tutorial "Write Views That Actually Do Something"

Tags: python, regex, django

I've been working on the Django tutorial. I'm on the part where it is "Write Views That Actually Do something." (Part 3)

I'm trying to use the index.html template that it gives you, but I keep getting a 404 error that says

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/index.html

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$ [name='results']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
^admin/
The current URL, polls/index.html, didn't match any of these.
```

I don't know if one of the regex are wrong? I've been messing around with it for a while now and I have had no luck getting it to work.

I can go to /polls just fine. But /polls/index.html does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

The version of Django that I'm using is 1.7.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django view functions or classes use the template you define, so that you do not have to specify it in the URL. The `urls.py` file matches your defined regex to send requests to views.

If you *truly* wanted to use that URL, you would have to define `^polls/index.html$` in your `urls.py` and direct it to your view.

Comment: Do I add that in the /mysite/polls/urls.py file, or the /mysite/mysite/urls.py?

Comment: If you already send anything matching `polls` to your `polls/urls.py`, then you would need to define `^index.html$` in your `mysite/polls/urls.py`

Comment: The problem with `mysite` in the tutorials if I remember, is that `mysite` is the project and the app. You could just have `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` in the `mysite` dir, then do `python manage.py startapp myapp` and you'll have a `models.py` `views.py` and `urls.py` in that. Add `myapp` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and then put your `/polls/` urls in `myapp`

Answer (score 0):

From what you're asking it sounds like you essentially want to output a static html file on a URL defined in your `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`.

I strongly suggest you take a look at Class Based Views.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf

The quickest way to go from what you've got, to rendering `polls/index.html` would be something like;

```
# some_app/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^polls/index.html', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
)
```

But I'm sure you'll want to pass things to the template so class based views will be what you need. So the alternative to the above with added context would be;

```
# some_app/views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Index, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['foo'] = 'bar'
        return context
```

Then obviously adding `{{ foo }}` to your `index.html` would output bar to the user. And you'd update your `urls.py` to;

```
# some_app/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from .views import Index

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    (r'^polls/index.html', Index.as_view()),
)
```